# Подключение VPN fedora

Tags: linux, vpn, fedora, l2tp

Прошу помощи в подключении vpn clienta, протокол L2TP, Шифрование IPSEC, на стороне сервера ОС Microsoft.Домашний ноут на linux fedora 27.

Comment: Ну, а чё не работает? И как не работает? Что уже делал?

Comment: Клиент - GNU/Linux F27, сервер MS Win? Гляньте, что есть из стандартных пакетов: dnf search vpn. Я обычно ставлю все, что есть: # dnf install \*vpn\* -y